# openCV 2.4.8 iOS 7.0 framework linker errors

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm not able to build a project in Xcode 5.0.2 using (the latest) openCV iOS framework release. I've been trying to use the pre-built framework downloaded from the openCV sourceforge page. I followed the steps on the openCV tutorial to add the framework to Xcode, and I also tried adding the libc++.dylib and/or the libstdc++.dylib binaries to the project as well.

The error I get is a preprocessing /lexical error that says it cannot find the file 
        `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`
 but in the Xcode file navigator I can indeed see it. If I don't `#include` the `opencv.hpp` file I get about 30 linker errors when I try to build the project. Any ideas about how to get this to work? I've seen some other posts here, and I've tried to build the framework from source myself, but nothing has seemed to exactly match my problem.

UPDATE:
Also to be more clear - I'm using Xcode 5.0.2, target build is iOS 7.0 for standard architectures (armv7 and armv7s).

C++ compiler is Apple LLVM 5.0, C++ language dialect setting is "compiler default" and C++ compiler setting is "libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I did get it to work, I just had to add the other frameworks that were required to get it to build. You can find them on this page : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing

Answer (score 3):

Using the pre-build iOS framework available on opencv.org is easy:

1. add the opencv2.framework to your project

   [image]
2. in your project's prefix header file (.pch) add

   ```
   #ifdef __cplusplus
       #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
   #endif
   ```

   which will import OpenCV's header in all C++ source file
3. start using OpenCV in any C++ source file.

What I'm guessing is that you're trying to use OpenCV in `.m` files, which by default are Objective-C (not C++) files. Since the OpenCV framework for iOS is written in C++ you can use it only in C++ source files.

The easiest way to add an Objectice-C++ file to Xcode is to set the extension of the source files to `.mm`.

Alternatively (and just for the records) you can change the File type to `Objective-C++ Source` in the "File inspector"

[image]

or add the `-x objective-c++`compiler flag  in the target's build phase.

[image]

Comment: Hey Tomas thanks for the reply. That's exactly what I did. I actually already have some C++ code in other .m files right now. I'm just trying to get the project to build before I start writing other Obj C objects with openCV. I'll also make an edit posting what my other c++ compiler settings are

Comment: Did you check that your target's "Framework search path" is properly set (path to the opecv2.framework)?

Comment: Weird. I just tried with an empty project using Xcode 5.0.2 and it works out of the box...

Comment: I guess I can try that too, maybe something weird with my Xcode setup. I also have the project (thankfully!) under source control and backed up online. If I can't get it to work with what I have now perhaps I'll delete from my machine, and redownload the project. Will that work in some cases?

Comment: Ok, so I was able to get opencv to work in a blank project. Maybe I'll give re-downloading the whole thing a shot.